# calculate difference of working hours in succussive rows of a column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, diff

I have a PANDAS data frame and I want to `groupby` with respect to `'type'` column and then calculate working-hour difference of each row of `'date'` column with the previous row. Desired output should be:

```
type       date                         working_hour_diff
  A      2020-01-02 07:07:20.963           15.0086
  A      2020-01-03 07:07:51.453             NaN
  B      2020-01-05 10:52:38.690           26.18
  B      2020-01-07 18:10:50.690             NaN
```

So far, I have tried this. First I defined a function using a library named `business_duration`:

```
def working_hours(startdate):
    from business_duration import businessDuration
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import time,datetime
    enddate = startdate.shift(1) 

    starttime=time(7,0,0)
    endtime=time(22,0,0)
    unit='hour'

    #By default weekends are Saturday and Sunday
    working_hours = businessDuration(startdate,enddate,starttime,endtime,unit=unit)
    return working_hours
```

And then I apply this function to my `'date'` column as follows:

```
df['working_hour_diff'] = df.groupby('type').date.apply(working_hours).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0):

Last step of calculating time can be changed `/ Hours_1` -> `/ 3600` but it returns datetime object

```py
df = pd.read_csv("hours.csv")
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

for t in df.type.unique():
    mask = df.type == t
    df.loc[mask, "work"] = df.loc[mask, "date"].shift(-1) - df.loc[mask, "date"]

Hours_24 = pd.to_timedelta(24,"H")
Hours_9 = pd.to_timedelta(9,"H")
Hours_1 = pd.to_timedelta(1,"H")

df.work = (df.work - Hours_9 * (df.work // Hours_24)) / Hours_1
print(df)
```

Explanation of last line in verbose code:

```py
whole_workdays_passed = df.work // Hours_24
time_office_was_closed = Hours_9 * whole_workdays_passed
time_office_was_open_as_datetime = df.work - time_office_was_closed
time_office_was_open_as_float = time_office_was_open_as_datetime / Hours_1
df.work = time_office_was_open_as_float
```

If office is open between 7-22 then that lefts 9 hours of closed time.
If next measurement is taken the same day `whole_workdays_passed` is 0. If next day, at least one night have passed, so we can subtract closed time.

Outputs:

```
  type                    date  working_hour_diff       work
0    A 2020-01-02 07:07:20.963            15.0086  15.008469
1    A 2020-01-03 07:07:51.453                NaN        NaN
2    B 2020-01-05 10:52:38.690            26.1800  37.303333
3    B 2020-01-07 18:10:50.690                NaN        NaN
```

last line also can be changed to:

```
df.work = (df.work - (3600*9) * (df.work // (24*3600) )) /  pd.to_timedelta(1,"H")
```

but it does not outputs the same answer.

```
  type                    date  working_hour_diff       work
0    A 2020-01-02 07:07:20.963            15.0086  15.005293
1    A 2020-01-03 07:07:51.453                NaN        NaN
2    B 2020-01-05 10:52:38.690            26.1800  34.564583
3    B 2020-01-07 18:10:50.690                NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The loop part works fine, but I don't understand what the last part of the code tries to do! I want to find the difference in the working hours, say the time the office is open, but the code finds the difference no matter when the times are, and then manipulates it.

Comment: i may have misunderstood the logic. could you elaborate how did you calculated result `26.1800` in `df[working_hour_diff]`

Comment: First thanks for the explanation, there are two points: first, your code did not consider weekends (and holidays); second, your code has a margin of error that is not negligible especially in the short terms. consider the difference between 2020-05-01 07:00:00 till 2020-05-02 22:00:00 that is 39 hours, and there are 9 hours of closedness. But from 2020-05-01 20:00:00 till 2020-05-03 11:00:00 the difference is, again, 39 hours but there are 18 hours of closedness.